# Captive Portal on Android 5.1+

Tags: openwrt, captiveportal, coovachilli

I want to use captive portal. I want the user to get authenticated after they accept the terms and conditions, followed by a redirect to the advertisement page.

However, when a user connects and is authenticated by the authentication server, the browser window is closed automatically on Android 5.1+. We want to keep it open so that we can show some advertisements after the user is authenticated.

This might not look like a technical post, but I want to know if anybody has some solution? If you think it's not possible to solve this, then please let us know. Or if you have any experience with such issue please share.

We are using openwrt 15.05 + wifidog.